# HTML textarea linebreak on enter key press don't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a textarea and when click enter it doesn't insert a linebreak,
I tried to use the following code, But, when i press enter, it goes to the end fo text and add new line.

```js
$("#descre").on('keydown', function(e) {
  var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
  if (code == 13) { //Enter keycode
    event.preventDefault();
    var s = $(this).val();
    $(this).val(s + "\n");
  }
});
```

I want to make a normal enter press, like ex: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k6o93zr5/)

Comment: your code explicitly adds a new-line at the end of the text. what are you expecting it to work?

Comment: why do oyu need custom JS anyways?

Comment: @PhilippSander i whant a custom js becuose my textarea is not working as a normal ...and a dont know why, so i'm short on time and a need a fix

Comment: the new line is always added at the end because of this line `$(this).val(s+"\n");` you will need to find the cursor position and add the newline there

Comment: @PhilippSander can you tell me an exemple please?

Comment: put in some effort ;-) you can easily find the solution yourself

Comment: @PhilippSander  I just wanted to thank you, because you said exactly what I needed, and I solved the problem, i'm goig to post the answer

Comment: Why do even need JS for this? Adding a new line on return key press is the default behaviour...

Comment: @Rory McCrossan well i know what you are saying, but on this case it has  as the default behaviour is inline, so i needed a fast solution

Comment: That may be but, fast !== good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My textarea was not working well, so to accept enter key press on normal behaviour i used the code:

```js
$('#descre').keypress(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.value = this.value.substring(0, this.selectionStart) + "" + "\n" + this.value.substring(this.selectionEnd, this.value.length);
  }
});
```

Comment: As I asked on your question, why do you need this? Adding a line break on return keypress is default behaviour for a `textarea`. If it's not working for you then you need to fix that issue, not put a bandaid on using JS. This is very far from a good solution.

Comment: Also note that concatenating the empty string is redundant.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan i think the problem is on the bootstrap.js file, but i need time to see what has happend

And tanks for the note, i didnt saw that

Comment: Bootstrap does not interfere with textarea operation.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan this I did not know, I'm a beginner in this area, the files I'm working on were created by a former co-worker, who is no longer present, that part of the code was made separately and inserted in the current code, the current code do not have these problems

Comment: @Rory McCrossan the current code is what i'm doing until now

Answer (score 1):

You have passed e in the function as argument but in the if block you are doing `event.preventDefault()` change it to `e.preventDefault()`

```
//i try this one 

    $("#descre").on('keydown', function(e) {
        var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
          if(code == 13) { //Enter keycode
           e.preventDefault();
           var s = $(this).val();
           $(this).val(s);
          }     
         });
```

You are adding an extra line in the end yourself. Thats why it is inserting the extra k=line

Comment: i understand what you saying, tanks for the heads up, but if i insert a newe line on the midle of text it dont take the text for the new line

Comment: This code takes the current value and sets it as the current value. It's completely pointless.